# Why isn't the next poster in my program showing up?

Tags: javascript, image

This is a program written for my ap computer science principles class. My programm is written in javascript with the use of code.org App Lab. The first poster shows up however after the first attempt the poster no longer shows up.

The code:

```js
// Variables that stay the same

var correctGuesses = 0;
var Guesses = 0;
var placeOnMovieList = 0;
var movies = getColumn("IMDB Top 1000", "Series_Title");
var movie_Posters = getColumn("IMDB Top 1000", "Poster_Link");

// Variables that change

var current_Movie_Poster = (movie_Posters[placeOnMovieList]);
var current_Movie_Name = (movies[placeOnMovieList]);

// Console Log so i know the awnser when testing

console.log(current_Movie_Name);

// This function sets up the UI to after pressing the start button

function startUI() {
  setScreen("screen2");
  setActiveCanvas("poster");
  drawImageURL(current_Movie_Poster);
}

// Creates UI when start button is created

onEvent("start_Button", "click", function( ) {
  startUI();
  console.log("StartButton clicked!");
});


/* Created due to issues with using startUI after a geuss 
 *  Shows a new Poster */
 
/* function recreateUI() {
  setScreen("screen2");
  clearCanvas();
  deleteElement("poster");
  console.log(current_Movie_Poster);
  drawImageURL(current_Movie_Poster);
}
*/

function recreateUI() {
  setScreen("screen2");
  clearCanvas();
  setActiveCanvas("poster"); // Set the active canvas for drawing
  drawImageURL(current_Movie_Poster); // Draw the new movie poster
}

/* Takes the Geuss given uses the function is_It_Correct function 
 * to compare the geuss to the actual movie */
 
onEvent("guess_Button", "click", function( ) {
  var user_Guess = getProperty("text_Input", "text");
  setProperty("text_Input", "text", "");
  console.log("Checking user guess");
  checkGuess(user_Guess, current_Movie_Name);
  setProperty("text_Input", "text", "");
});



function checkGuess(user_Guess, movie_Name) {
  Guesses++;
  user_Guess = user_Guess.toLowerCase();
  movie_Name = movie_Name.toLowerCase();
  
  if (user_Guess.trim().length === 0) {
    badGuess();
    return;
  }
  
  // Loops through each character
  for (var i = 0; i < user_Guess.length - 1; i++) {
    if (user_Guess.charAt(i) !== movie_Name.charAt(i)) {
      badGuess(); // Call badGuess if characters don't match
      return;
    }
  }

  // If the loop finishes without returning, the input and team name match
  correctGuesses++;
  console.log("User Guess Correct");
  goodGuess();
}

/* Moves to the next team in the dataset 
 * or ends the quiz */

function teamSelect(){
  if (movies.length  >=  placeOnMovieList) {
    placeOnMovieList++;
    current_Movie_Poster = (movies[placeOnMovieList]);
    current_Movie_Name = (movie_Posters[placeOnMovieList]);
    console.log(current_Movie_Poster);
    console.log(current_Movie_Name);
  }
}

// Sets up a UI to continue afetr a correct guess

/* function goodGuess() {
  setScreen("screen3");
  teamSelect();
  onEvent("correct_Continue_Button", "click", function( ) {
    if (placeOnMovieList < movies.length) {
      recreateUI();
      return;
    }else{
      endQuiz();
      return;
    }
  });
  
}
*/

function goodGuess() {
  setScreen("screen3");
  teamSelect(); // Call teamSelect to update movie data
  onEvent("correct_Continue_Button", "click", function( ) {
    if (placeOnMovieList < movies.length) {
      recreateUI();
      return;
    } else {
      endQuiz();
      return;
    }
  });
}


// Sets up a UI to continue afetr a bad guess

function badGuess() {
  setScreen("screen4");
  teamSelect();
  onEvent("incorrect_Continue_Button", "click", function( ) {
    if (placeOnMovieList < movies.length) {
      recreateUI();
      return;
    }else{
      endQuiz();
      return;
    }
  });
}

// Ends quiz and tells you score

function endQuiz() {
  setScreen("screen5");
  var percentageCorrect = Math.round((correctGuesses / Guesses) * 100); // Calculate here
  console.log(percentageCorrect + "%");
  textLabel("grade", ("You got " + percentageCorrect + "% correct"));
  setPosition("grade", 155, 210, 100, 100);
  return;
}
```

I have already tried deleting and then recreating the poster element. I have also already tested to make sure the images in the dataset accessed are still working.

Comment: Perhaps don't call functions "events" but use actual event handlers which should help add clarity to your solution that you can pare down to a more focused approach.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain what you are trying to do and what is the error.